# Saving youtube api data in python

Tags: python, api, nameerror

I am new to python. I have used youtube api to get data from youtube. Now, I am trying to save the data into csv format but I am getting error:

> NameError: name 'search_response' is not defined. I don't know what I am doing wrong or there is some package installation issue here.

I am using python 3.6.3 and the following code:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

from apiclient.discovery import build
#from apiclient.errors import HttpError
#from oauth2client.tools import argparser # removed by Dongho
import argparse
import csv
import unidecode

# Set DEVELOPER_KEY to the API key value from the APIs & auth > Registered apps
# tab of
#   https://cloud.google.com/console
# Please ensure that you have enabled the YouTube Data API for your project.
DEVELOPER_KEY = " "
YOUTUBE_API_SERVICE_NAME = "youtube"
YOUTUBE_API_VERSION = "v3"

def youtube_search(options):
    youtube = build(YOUTUBE_API_SERVICE_NAME, YOUTUBE_API_VERSION, 
                    developerKey=DEVELOPER_KEY)
    # Call the search.list method to retrieve results matching the specified
    # query term.
    search_response = youtube.search().list(q=options.q, part="id,snippet", 
                                            maxResults=options.max_results).execute()

    videos = []
    channels = []
    playlists = []

    # create a CSV output for video list    
    csvFile = open('video_result.csv','w')
    csvWriter = csv.writer(csvFile)
    csvWriter.writerow(["title","videoId","viewCount","likeCount","dislikeCount",
                        "commentCount","favoriteCount"])

    # Add each result to the appropriate list, and then display the lists of
    # matching videos, channels, and playlists.
    for search_result in search_response.get("items", []):
        if search_result["id"]["kind"] == "youtube#video":
            #videos.append("%s (%s)" % (search_result["snippet"]["title"],\
            #                           search_result["id"]["videoId"]))
            title = search_result["snippet"]["title"]
            title = unidecode.unidecode(title)  # Dongho 08/10/16
            videoId = search_result["id"]["videoId"]
            video_response = youtube.videos().list(id=videoId,part="statistics").execute()
            for video_result in video_response.get("items",[]):
                viewCount = video_result["statistics"]["viewCount"]
                if 'likeCount' not in video_result["statistics"]:
                    likeCount = 0
                else:
                    likeCount = video_result["statistics"]["likeCount"]
                if 'dislikeCount' not in video_result["statistics"]:
                    dislikeCount = 0
                else:
                    dislikeCount = video_result["statistics"]["dislikeCount"]
                if 'commentCount' not in video_result["statistics"]:
                    commentCount = 0
                else:
                    commentCount = video_result["statistics"]["commentCount"]
                if 'favoriteCount' not in video_result["statistics"]:
                    favoriteCount = 0
                else:
                    favoriteCount = video_result["statistics"]["favoriteCount"]

            csvWriter.writerow([title,videoId,viewCount,likeCount,dislikeCount,
                                commentCount,favoriteCount])

    csvFile.close()
```

Comment: What is the type of the 'options' variable you pass into youtube_search ?  I'm wondering if search_response doesn't get set because of an issue with that, but I can't help without knowing that.

Comment: def youtube_search(q, max_results=50,order="relevance", token=None, location=None, location_radius=None):
I am still getting the same error. Please help

Comment: I am getting same problem with another youtube data, I tried:  `def videos_list_most_popular(client, **kwargs):   
 kwargs = remove_empty_kwargs(**kwargs)  
 response = client.videos().list(**kwargs).execute()  
 Data = json.loads(str(response,'utf-8'))`  
NameError: name 'response' is not defined

Comment: when you do `def youtube_search(q, max_results=50,order="relevance", token=None, location=None, location_radius=None)` what is 'q'?

Comment: The q parameter specifies the query term to search for. The code must be running fine as I am able to get the results. I don't know why I am unable to load the results for further analysis.

Comment: Without seeing what is in `options` no one can diagnose.  If I place your logic outside of a function and remove the `q=` param and the `maxResults` param from `youtube.search().list` it works just fine.

Comment: I tried to extract popular videos data from youtube and am facing similar problem. Do you think you can take a look? The code must be running fine there.https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48914049/most-popular-youtube-videos-from-youtube-api

Comment: I put what I did here: https://gist.github.com/tadamhicks/bfb13306428e5da1b29e122fc5c8025b This works, though I'm sure isn't what you want.  Agin, without seeing how you format your query and pass it I cannot diagnose.