# Most popular youtube videos from Youtube API

Tags: python, csv, youtube, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I am trying to get popular YouTube videos data using python. While I can successfully download the data, I cannot store it or save it in csv format. Here is the code I used:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import os

import google.oauth2.credentials

import google_auth_oauthlib.flow
from googleapiclient.discovery import build
from googleapiclient.errors import HttpError
from google_auth_oauthlib.flow import InstalledAppFlow


CLIENT_SECRETS_FILE = "client_secret.json"


SCOPES = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube.force-ssl']
API_SERVICE_NAME = 'youtube'
API_VERSION = 'v3'

def get_authenticated_service():
  flow = InstalledAppFlow.from_client_secrets_file(CLIENT_SECRETS_FILE, SCOPES)
  credentials = flow.run_console()
  return build(API_SERVICE_NAME, API_VERSION, credentials = credentials)

def print_response(response):
  print(response)


def build_resource(properties):
  resource = {}
  for p in properties:
   
    prop_array = p.split('.')
    ref = resource
    for pa in range(0, len(prop_array)):
      is_array = False
      key = prop_array[pa]

      # For properties that have array values, convert a name like
      # "snippet.tags[]" to snippet.tags, and set a flag to handle
      # the value as an array.
      if key[-2:] == '[]':
        key = key[0:len(key)-2:]
        is_array = True

      if pa == (len(prop_array) - 1):
        # Leave properties without values out of inserted resource.
        if properties[p]:
          if is_array:
            ref[key] = properties[p].split(',')
          else:
            ref[key] = properties[p]
      elif key not in ref:
        # For example, the property is "snippet.title", but the resource does
        # not yet have a "snippet" object. Create the snippet object here.
        # Setting "ref = ref[key]" means that in the next time through the
        # "for pa in range ..." loop, we will be setting a property in the
        # resource's "snippet" object.
        ref[key] = {}
        ref = ref[key]
      else:
        # For example, the property is "snippet.description", and the resource
        # already has a "snippet" object.
        ref = ref[key]
  return resource

# Remove keyword arguments that are not set
def remove_empty_kwargs(**kwargs):
  good_kwargs = {}
  if kwargs is not None:
    for key, value in kwargs.iteritems():
      if value:
        good_kwargs[key] = value
  return good_kwargs

def videos_list_most_popular(client, **kwargs):
  # See full sample for function
  kwargs = remove_empty_kwargs(**kwargs)

  response = client.videos().list(
    **kwargs
  ).execute()

  return print_response(response)


if __name__ == '__main__':
  # When running locally, disable OAuthlib's HTTPs verification. When
  # running in production *do not* leave this option enabled.
  os.environ['OAUTHLIB_INSECURE_TRANSPORT'] = '1'
  client = get_authenticated_service()
  
  videos_list_most_popular(client,
    part='snippet,contentDetails,statistics',
    chart='mostPopular',
    regionCode='US',
    videoCategoryId='')
```

How do I save the result in csv format? I tried the following code but got an error:

> Data = json.loads(str(response,'utf-8'))
>
> NameError: name 'response' is not defined

Answer (score 1):

NameError means that the variable `response` isn't in the context where you are running it. I don't know where you put that line in the code, but you call the `videos_list_most_popular` function which will not return any data.

The `videos_list_most_popular` returns the result of the `print_response` function. But since that function only prints the response, and not actually returns anything it will return `None` and then down below where you execute `videos_list_most_popular` the result will be None.

And it will also dissappear because you don't assign the result of that function to anything (which would look like: `response = videos_list_most_popular(...)`).

You will need to change `videos_list_most_popular` so it returns `response` and then assign that return value like I did above. Then you can execute the line you wrote.

Comment: Thank you. But now I am getting a different error:`Data = json.loads(str(response,'utf-8'))` TypeError: decoding to str: need a bytes-like object, NoneType found

Comment: The error is saying that the `str(...)` function needs a bytes-like object. But it gets a `None`. Apparently the variable `response` is `None` instead of the list of video's that you are expecting.
Can you update your question to reflect your current file again? Easier for me to see what is happening :-)

Comment: How do I assign the result? Can you be more specific please?

Comment: Like I wrote in my answer: `response = videos_list_most_popular(...)`

Comment: I tried : `def videos_list_most_popular(client, **kwargs):  
 kwargs = remove_empty_kwargs(**kwargs)
 response = client.videos().list(**kwargs).execute()
 video_response = videos_list_most_popular(client,
    part='snippet,contentDetails,statistics',
    chart='mostPopular',
    regionCode='US',
    videoCategoryId='')
 return video_response
 
if __name__ == '__main__':
  
  os.environ['OAUTHLIB_INSECURE_TRANSPORT'] = '1'
  client = get_authenticated_service()`But `print (video_response)`returns None

Comment: This is hard to see in a comment, can you update your question with what you currently have?

Comment: Thank you. I assigned the result of the function to a variable and it worked.